# Restrict autonav display in concrete5

Tags: php, concrete5

I'm new to concrete5, and I'm wondering if its possible to remove the breadcrumb navigation bar from certain pages.. If so, how? Otherwise it's fine.

I've heard I can create a checkbox in page attribute and then configuring the .php file to include this function.

Here is a sample of what the code would look like:

```
    <div id="breadcrumbs">
    <?php 
        if ($ca->getCollectionAttributeValue('hide_breadcrumb') != '1');
        $an = new GlobalArea('autonav');
        $an->display($ca);
        endif;
    ?>
</div>
```

It gave me a fatal error of some sort..

> Fatal error: Call to a member function getCollectionAttributeValue()
>   on a non-object

Im guessing that isnt recognized though I've defined the attribute as hide_breadcrumb..

Thank you and have a nice day.

Answer (score 0):

I have to ask..  Why are you editing the php file?

Can you not just add/remove perms of the block when in Edit mode?

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Um it's for a search page. I don't want the breadcrumb nav there.. It's in a global area so I tried to inmplement a hide_nav attribute but it's giving me alot of errors..

Comment: Oh btw, I think that must be an updated ver of C5 which I'm not using btw.. or rather not allowed to. There's no such option..

Comment: So I googled that and it came out to Advance Permissions or something like that which I'm denied access to, including permissions on blocks and stacks and page permissions.

Answer (score 0):

Your approach seems a bit hacky, but I honestly can't think of a better way right now...

With that being said, why are you using `$ca`? The error (`Call to a member function on a non-object`) is referring to the `$ca`, not to the `hide_breadcrumb` or anything else.

You should be able to use $c, which is the c5-wide global variable for the page. Even better, don't use globals, and do something like

`Page::getCurrentPage()->getCollectionAttributeValue`

(or you can assign the currentPage to a variable first...)